# Java ME and Java EE communication

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-me

I want to make a Java ME application that sends a message to a server (Tomcat, Java EE). The server should then send a message back to this Java ME application.

What is the request/response model between Java ME and Java EE (Tomcat server)?

Comment: Question is very unclear. What kind of client/server is it?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is use HTTP to do that. So, on the JavaME end, you will issue HTTP REQUEST that will call a Servlet running in your JavaEE AppServer and processing the request.

Comment: @Palo any relevant tutorial if you can share which explain via code
example or text tutoial....